# Player randomly changing position after implementing UI elements

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine, position

So I've been following a tutorial on making a 2D game in Unity (I'm a complete newbie, this is my first contact with programming), and I wanted to add a feature to the game(bold).
 The "heart system" that I added works correctly (the number of empty hearts is equal to damage taken by player), but it caused my player to transform his position in a wierd way. You can see, that there are boundries set (maxHeight =3,2, minHeight=-3,2), and the value of his movement as well (Yincrement = 3.2) and yet, after pressing up or down arrowkeys he seems to change Y position by around 4.67.
 Here's the player script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Vector2 targetPos;
    public float Yincrement;

    public float speed;
    public float maxHeight;
    public float minHeigth;

    public int health = 3;
    public int numOfHearts;

    public Image[] hearts;
    public Sprite heartFull;
    public Sprite heartEmpty;

    public GameObject effect;

    public Image healthDisplay;

    private void Update()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < hearts.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i < health)
            {
                hearts[i].sprite = heartFull;
            }
            else
            {
                hearts[i].sprite = heartEmpty;

                if (i < numOfHearts)
                {
                    hearts[i].enabled = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    hearts[i].enabled = false;
                }
            }

            if (health <= 0)
            {
                SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
            }

            transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPos, speed * Time.deltaTime);

            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow) && transform.position.y < maxHeight)
            {
                Instantiate(effect, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
                targetPos = new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y + Yincrement);
            }
            else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow) && transform.position.y > minHeigth)
            {
                Instantiate(effect, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);

                targetPos = new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y - Yincrement);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Decide on a [naming convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)) (I _**strongly**_ recommend one equal or similar to Rider/Resharper's), make your code at least _somewhat_ readable by humans (get rid of those empty lines at the ends of blocks), then we can talk.

Comment: Your `for` loop should onyl enclose the UI part ... you are doing your movement within the `for` loop so it will be executed `hearts.Length` times. Also your clamping of the position is insecure ... imagine the current position being `3.1` which is `< maxHeight` so you add the increment once and it results in a maximum possible height of `6.3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Main Issue

The main problem is your `for` loop. It should only be used for updating the UI - **not** for multiple times calling your movement and Scene reload! You should close your `for` loop earlier.

```
for (int i = 0; i < hearts.Length; i++)
{
    // you can also reduce these to single lines
    hearts[i].enabled = i < numOfHearts;

    if(i < numOfHearts) hearts[i].sprite = i < health ? heartFull : heartEmpty;    
} // <-- ALREADY CLOSE IT HERE

if(health <= 0) ...

...
```

#### Position clamping

Your clamping of the position is extremely insecure! Imagine the current position being `3.1` which is still `< maxHeight` so you add the `Yincrement` once and it results in a maximum possible height of `6.3`! That's not what you wanted.

You should clamp directly on the `targetPosition` not on the current `transform.position`. You could for example use [`Mathf.Clamp`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Clamp.html) for making sure the `targetPos.y` always stays within the given range.

Also since both cases do something very similar I would reduce this to only one movement using a simply `int` variable for setting the direction:

```
...

transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPos, speed * Time.deltaTime);

var move = 0;
var targetPosY = targePos.y;

if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow) && targetPosY < maxHeight)
{
    move = 1;
}
else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow) && targetPosY > minHeigth)
{
    move = -1;
}

// Handle the movement according to the direction
// in one single code block for both directions
if(move != 0)
{
    Instantiate(effect, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);

    // increase/decrease the targetPosY according to the move direction
    targetPosY += move * Yincrement;
    // Now make sure it is within the range
    targetPosY = Mathf.Clamp(targetPosY, minHeight, maxHeight);

    // finally assign the new target position
    targetPos = new Vector2(transform.position.x, targetPosY);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. If it helps, my game is supposed to be a simple endless runner, where the player must avoid obstacles by moving into one of three rows, upper, middle, or lower. I have a slight issue when it comes to your corrected code. In   targetPosY = Mathf.Clamp(targetPos, minHeight, maxHeight); targetPos can't be converted to float and being a beginner, I don't have a clue how to fix that :(

Comment: Oh sorry little typo! It should be `targetPosY` here not `targetPos`. Either my brain or smartphone autocorrect must have eaten the `Y` ;)

Comment: Thank you so much, it works perfectly! This project is really exciting for me and makes me wanna learn more coding! I know very little about it right now, but the possibilities seem endless.

Comment: Glad to help! Please feel free to accept `✔` the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Could you please specify in detail what your game is about and what you are trying to do in each part of the script. I might be able to help you then. Also, if this is your first contact with programming, this is way to advanced. Start with something simpler and first understand the basic concepts of programming before moving on. Here is a good tutorial series to learn c# programming for absolute beginners.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pSiIHe2uZ2w

I am not sure what you are trying to do but why is your movement control within your for loop. That might be why your are messing up. Try removing all of this code out of the for loop.

```
transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPos, speed * Time.deltaTime);

if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow) && transform.position.y < maxHeight)
{
    Instantiate(effect, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
    targetPos = new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y + Yincrement);
}
else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow) && transform.position.y > minHeigth)
{
    Instantiate(effect, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);

    targetPos = new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y - Yincrement);
}
```

Also this code should be after you check if the player has moved.

```
transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPos, speed * Time.deltaTime);
```

Here is a tip to make movement a little easier. Use transform.translate instead of Vector2.MoveTowards. Transform.translate takes in 3 floats and changes you player's position by the three floats represented as a vector.

Here is an example

```
transform.translate(0,2,0);
```

This will change the players y position by 2. I thing your code should look like this.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Vector2 targetPos;
    public float Yincrement;

    public float speed;
    public float maxHeight;
    public float minHeigth;

    public int health = 3;
    public int numOfHearts;

    public Image[] hearts;
    public Sprite heartFull;
    public Sprite heartEmpty;

    public GameObject effect;

    public Image healthDisplay;

    private void Update()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < hearts.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i < health)
            {
                hearts[i].sprite = heartFull;
            }
            else
            {
                hearts[i].sprite = heartEmpty;

                if (i < numOfHearts)
                {
                    hearts[i].enabled = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    hearts[i].enabled = false;
                }
            }
        }

        if (health <= 0)
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow) && transform.position.y < maxHeight)
        {
            transform.Translate(0,Yincrement,0)
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow) && transform.position.y > minHeigth)
        {
            Instantiate(effect, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);

            transform.Translate(0,Yincrement,0);
        }
    }
}
```

After I receive your reply, I possibly could help but there are no guarantees because I only have about a years worth of experience too.

Comment: note that `transform.Translate` starts with a capital `T`. And after using it you missed a `;`. Also now you do not `Instantiate` for the `KeyCode.UpArrow` case

Comment: You don't want to use `Translate` here because it makes the object immediately **jump** to that position!  And also the clamping of position is still extremely insecure:  imagine the current position being `3.1` which is `< maxHeight` so you add the increment once and it results in a maximum possible height of `6.3`

Comment: oh yeah. Silly me. He should use vector2.movetowards but he still shouldn't have all of that within the for loop.